# Updating ac existing file using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro which normally filters data based on the selection from the drop down menu and creates a new file and saves it based on the selection criteria. However I would like to change it in a way so that instead of creating a new file every time it just updates the existing file of my choosing in the folder of my choosing. whats the best way to do that?
here's the vba code that I'm using at the moment:

```
   Sub macro_apac()
   Windows("Historic list COMPIL FY18.xlsm").Activate

   Workbooks.Add    
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\New folder\historic list asia pacific.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

   Windows("Historic list COMPIL FY18.xlsm").Activate

   Sheets(Array("Liste_complete Q4FY17", "Historic list", _
    "Graph-Deployment progress", "Consolidation-Budget FY18", _
    "Consolidation-Forecast FY18", "Back up info")).Select


   Sheets(Array("Liste_complete Q4FY17", "Historic list", _
    "Graph-Deployment progress", "Consolidation-Budget FY18", _
    "Consolidation-Forecast FY18", "Back up info")).Copy Before:=Workbooks( 
   _
    "historic list asia pacific.xlsx").Sheets(1)

    Windows("historic list asia pacific.xlsx").Activate    
   Sheets("Liste_complete Q4FY17").Range("$A$1:$DU$15000").AutoFilter 
   Field:=70, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "BENELUX", "BRAZIL", "CEE", "DACH", "France", "LATAM", "MED", "NORAM", 
   "NORDICS", _
    "UK & I"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A1").Activate
    Dim a As Long, b As Long
    a = ActiveCell.Row
    b = ActiveCell.Column
    Do
    a = a + 1
    Loop Until Cells(a, b).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows(a).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Delete
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below should delete listed sheets in a picked file and replace them with listed sheets from "Historic list COMPIL FY18.xlsm" then do the filtering thing but provided code does not seem complete.

```
Sub macro_apac()

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook, Fil As String

    Set Wb1 = Workbooks("Historic list COMPIL FY18.xlsm")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show <> 0 Then
            Fil = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No file selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Fil)

    arr = Array("Liste_complete Q4FY17", "Historic list", "Graph-Deployment progress", "Consolidation-Budget FY18", "Consolidation-Forecast FY18", "Back up info")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For i = 1 To Wb2.Sheets.Count
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr)
                If Wb2.Sheets(i).Name = arr(j) Then Wb2.Sheets(i).Delete
            Next j
        Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Wb1.Sheets(arr).Copy before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)

    Wb2.Sheets("Liste_complete Q4FY17").Activate

    Sheets("Liste_complete Q4FY17").Range("$A$1:$DU$15000").AutoFilter Field:=70, Criteria1:=Array("BENELUX", "BRAZIL", "CEE", "DACH", "France", "LATAM", "MED", "NORAM", "NORDICS", "UK & I"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A1").Activate
    Dim a As Long, b As Long
    a = ActiveCell.Row
    b = ActiveCell.Column
    Do
    a = a + 1
    Loop Until Cells(a, b).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows(a).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Delete
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter

    '[...]

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\New folder\historic list asia pacific.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

At the end of your code add:

`ActiveWorkbook.Save`

Comment: thanks for your response but my bad, i didn't phrase the question very well. what i meant by updating the existing file was that I want the macro to update the file by the name of historic list asia pacific.xlsx already in the path ""C:\New folder\historic list asia pacific.xlsx".

Comment: @UmmadArif , do you want to update the data in a file or do you want to create a new file and replace the old one? Please try to be a little more precise so we can help you.

Comment: @dalder sorry for the confusion.  I want to update the data in an existing file  instead of creating a new one.